# Awkward terms in Differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the equation:

$(x^2+y^2+x)d x-(2x^2+2y^2-y)dy=0$

As a standard approach, I brought $dy/dx$ to the RHS of the equation. Then, I added and subtracted $x^2+y^2-y$ to the numerator of the LHS to find some symmetric relation between the numerator and denominator. Perfecting squares of the numerator or the denominator does not help either. Please advice.

Comment: Without really having a good clue of why this might be useful, have you tried converting to polar coordinates? As $x^2+y^2+x=r^2+r\cos\theta$ and $2x^2+2y^2-y=2r^2-r\sin\theta$..

Comment: Integrating once gives $-x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+2y=k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation can be written as

$$xdx +ydy + (x^2+y^2)(dx-2dy) = 0$$

Away from $(x,y) = (0,0)$ we can divide by $x^2+y^2$ to get

$$\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dx + \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} dy + (dx-2dy) = 0,$$

which is the same as

$$d(\frac{1}{2}\ln({x^2+y^2)} + x-2y) = 0. $$

That leads to $\frac{1}{2}\ln{(x^2+y^2)} +x-2y = k$, as in @almagest's comment.

Comment: elusive perfect differential...